# Odoo v9 - Set a dynamic domain when EDITING a form (not creating)

Tags: python, odoo, view

Lets say you are setting a field called "Animal Type", and there is a field dependent upon this called "Favorite toy".  If the "Animal Type" is a dog, I'd want to set the domain of "Favorite toy" to something like ('isdogtoy','=',True). If its a cat, then maybe we set it to False or some other condition.

Normally to set dynamic domains, you'd use onchange, and then set the domain for the field.

However, there are cases where nothing changes. For instance, if you edit an existing record, onchange isn't necessarily called. If I never change the "Animal Type", then my domain on "Favorite Toy" is never set through my onchange method.

I'm not sure how we do this dynamically in Odoo.  It seems like there obviously should be a way, but I can't find anything on this.

Comment: i don't really understand what you mean, if field `y` depends on field `x`, how can any change in field `y` be triggered, if x doesn't change?. *dynamic* (something that changes) domains has to be based on something that changes. i suspect that you want a default domain but i can never know until you clarify.

Comment: Well, to put it plainly, I have an onchange that does what I described in the question.  It works great when I'm making a new record.  However, after I save the record and go back in and edit it, the domain is reset to the default.  

From a user's perspective, this really doesn't make any sense.  When they were creating the record, the choices they were given for "Favorite Toy" were specific to the animal they chose.  Now they went to change the "Favorite Toy", but Odoo presents them with a different domain of choices.  They should see the same choices they had the last time.

Comment: Ok, so I had the idea of making a computed field, and using that to help set the variables in the domain.... but I can't for the life of me get the computed field to be stored in the database.  Even with store=True, the values do not get saved.  

I swear, the newer api is infuriating.  I see all of these solutions that worked for v7, but there are no ways to do the same thing in v9.

Comment: Show us the code for your computed field solution, maybe we can work something out :-)

Comment: computed fields have to also use the `@api.depends` decorator. but we'll have to see some code (complete code with the associated views in the xml file) before we can give any answer

Comment: I was able to correct the issue with the computed field... Apparently, the return values aren't used to save the field to the DB.  You need to explicitly state self.mycomputedvariable = <value>  in the compute function.  This is still rather inflexible, as my domain statements are quickly becoming overly complex in order to accomplish what I want using the computed fields.  There really is no way of getting odoo to dynamically set the domain on loading the form edit?

Answer (score 2):

This is the best that I could come up with, using a computed field. Here is an example solution from my code

In my XML,

```
 <field name="uom_id" position="replace">
      <!-- The category_id.name is really only used to filter when islocaluom=True. The result is that if a uom_class is used, only uom's from that class can be selected.  Otherwise, the default uom's are present -->

      <field name="uom_id" groups="product.group_uom" domain="['&amp;',('islocaluom','=',calcislocaluom),'|',('islocaluom','=',False),('category_id','=',calccatidname)]" options="{'no_create' : True},{'no_create_edit' : True}" />
  </field>
```

Now I just created some computed fields using store=True, and then set them in the compute functions.

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'product.template'
  #This field will let us choose if we are using per product uom on the product
  uom_class = fields.Many2one('productuom.class', 'Per Product UOM Conversion Class', ondelete='restrict',required=False, help="Unit of Measure class for Per Product UOM")
  #These computed fields are for calculating the domain on a form edit
  calcislocaluom = fields.Boolean('Find if its a localuom',compute='_computelocaluom', store=True, default=False)
  calccatidname = fields.Char('Find the name of the category id', compute='_computecatidname', store=True,default=True)
  #[...] other code removed

  @api.one
  @api.depends('uom_class')
  def _computelocaluom(self):
      if (self.uom_class):
          self.calcislocaluom = True
          return True
      else:
          self.calcislocaluom = False
          return False

  @api.one
  @api.depends('uom_class')
  def _computecatidname(self):
      if (self.uom_class):
          self.calccatidname = self.uom_class.name
          return self.uom_class.name
      else:
          #Due to the conditions we later impose within the view, we need to specify a category name that will always be there
          self.calccatidname = "Unsorted/Imported Units"
          return True
```

I'm going to hold off on marking this as a correct answer, because its hard enough to create statically defined domains that actually do what I want them to, and act dynamically depending on the data.... but having to make these complicated statements in reverse polish notation is just torture.